# is numerous class for specific functions good?

Tags: java, android

my main activity has over 400 Lines Of Code and contains numerous methods which deals with pdf generations, making the page dynamic, and other condition checks..

i was wondering if i should make it all into different class files.. each specific for its task..  thereby creating at least 3-4 different classes..

so my query is 
1) will this approach make the app faster.. 
2) will this increase the app's size drastically??

also is there anyway to reduce the app's size? 
i have deleted all unnecessary pics, xml's & assests..
i just want the size to be below 5mb.. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

1) No. This won't noticably affect the app's speed.

2) No. The compiled code is actually the smallest part of an APK. Most of the size is caused by resources.

A way to reduce your app's size would be to optimize your compression on the images that are contained in your app. Also, you might be able to draw some of the images in code, as primitives such as lines, circles, squares, depending on what's on the images.

Answer (score 1):

These points may help you :

1. Java class files increase the app size which you can ignore because it is very very less. So that point you no need to be worried.
2. As you have mentioned you deleted images and all. Those things actually increase the app size. So delete those as many as possible is not being used.
3. Creating more classes which will be specific for their purposes, that is OOPs concept and it is very much recommended. So if you want to modify something in future iy will be easy for you find the code as well your code will be modified in that particular class made for that sole pupose.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) will this approach make the app faster?

Faster, can't comment. However, That approach will provide you an opportunity to learn how to make good design and will help you in future maintainability and extension of your project.

> 2) will this increase the app's size drastically?

Not at all.